# What does withRouter and props in routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm pretty new to React and trying to understand what a component does that I am trying to use in a project.

I used useHistory from react-router before but this looks so different. And it also seems like props is being used. Is there somebody here that understand and can explain what this component does. And what withRouter does and if it's the same as useHistory?

Thank you!

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const LinkButton = (props) => {
  const {
    history,
    location,
    match,
    staticContext,
    to,
    onClick,
    // ⬆ filtering out props that `button` doesn’t know what to do with.
    ...rest
  } = props
  return (
    <button
      {...rest} // `children` is just another prop!
      onClick={(event) => {
        onClick && onClick(event)
        history.push(to)
      }}
    />
  )
}

LinkButton.propTypes = {
  to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}

export default withRouter(LinkButton)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withRouter` is a [Higher Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to inject router props (`match`, `location`, `history`) to the wrapped component, `LinkButton`.

Under the hood it uses `RouterContext` to populate the `match`, `location`, `history` to the wrapped component.

```
function withRouter(Component) {
  const C = props => {
    const { wrappedComponentRef, ...remainingProps } = props;

    return (
      <RouterContext.Consumer>
        {context => {
          return (
            <Component
              {...remainingProps}
              {...context} // pass context (match, location, history)
              ref={wrappedComponentRef}
            />
          );
        }}
      </RouterContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}
```

While `useHistory` is just a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) in react router to use **only** `history` info within the **function** component.